# Interpreting RandomForestRegressor feature_importances_

Tags: python, feature-selection, random-forest

I have a Random Forest model for a dataset with 3 features:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10)
rf.fit(X, y)
```

If I look at the importance of each feature I get:

```
rf.feature_importances_

> array([ 0.45453475,  0.23246138,  0.31300387])
```

I know that feature 1 is the most important but how do I interpret these results exactly?  Could I say, for example, that 45% of the variability of the model is explained by feature 1?

Comment: See first https://explained.ai/rf-importance/

Answer (score 1):

The values are less directly translatable as probability percentages and more concerned with how *informative* [1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) the feature is relative to the other features.

"Informative" in this context refers to the information gained [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Information_gain) by splitting at this feature. If it is frequently chosen as the feature to split on across the many trees, it has a higher feature importance.

Answer (score 0):

Features more on top of the tree contribute to the final prediction of a larger fraction of the input samples than features deeper down inside the tree. The `feature_importances_` is an estimate to what fraction of the input samples' classification a feature contributes to.

1.0 would mean you have a feature that alone classifies all samples, 0.0 would indicate a feature that can add no (additional) value for classification.

The RandomForest calculates an average of these estimates to reduce variance of the importance estimates. You can use these values e.g. for feature selection.